# Magento 2 exporting issue

Tags: magento2, product, export

I try to export my products in **Magento 2.1.3**.
When i select to export products and csv files format and i press continue, a receive this message:

```
Please correct the data sent value.
```

And if i check the console i have this Ajax err:

http://myproject/admin/export/getFilter/key/746c4cfc21048351cc4aef84b013a591ff7f64893123bfa1cf6e730f8ba32e58/entity/catalog_product?isAjax=true

This problem appears only for products export, all the other options for export work well !

Does anyone know what caused this issue?

Comment: You should check error logs in var/logs

Comment: i don't have any err in var

Comment: Did you solve this Issue?